# Remove half second delay when minitest starts?

Tags: ruby, minitest

Consider this output when I use the bash `time` utility to benchmark a trivial minitest run:

```
$time ruby spec/trivial_spec.rb 
Run options: --seed 4156

# Running:

.

Finished in 0.001077s, 928.9209 runs/s, 928.9209 assertions/s.

1 runs, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips


real    0m0.443s
user    0m0.341s
sys 0m0.083s
```

As you can see, the test itself runs almost instantly (0.001s), but actually *permorming that test* takes nearly half a second, presumably because of the load time of minitest itself.

Is there any way to remove this delay?  Either through minitest config options or perhaps using another tool that preloads it?

Comment: The delay is because there are other actions that must be performed before running the test. If you want accurate timing, do it from directly in ruby]

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment, but the bash time is the one that's relevant for me.  I currently use guard to automatically re-run tests when files change, piping results into growl for my TDD cycle.  If my test takes 0.001s, I want the results to appear in growl instantly after I click save.  Guard itself picks up the change almost instantly, so I want to get rid of the minitest "infrastructure" delay somehow.

Comment: If you are shelling out to a Ruby command in your workflow, then there is not much "pre-loading" you can do. E.g. try just `time ruby -rminitest -e ''`

Comment: If you want to run benchmarks, you should be using [Benchmark](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html).

Comment: @NeilSlater, Ok, that helped.  Your command ran in 0.15s.  It turned out that my 0.43 was being caused by including 'minitest/autorun'.  After taking that out, my test runs in 0.15 from the command line.  However, the delay is still longer than that before my growl notification pops up.  It's strange, when I watch the test run, it's as if it's taking longer in the command line output when guard runs it than when I run it myself in bash...

Comment: @Jonah The latency of Growl will depend on how frequently and quickly the OS hands Growl filesystem change events (probably via fsevents) and how fast Growl processes them than how fast Ruby runs. Add a Growl change notification that does nothing but print and see what the delay is.

Comment: @Schwern, I have ruled out Growl and guard, as I can literally see that the latency occurs during the test itself in the console output as guard runs (ie, guard starts instantly after hitting save, and growl shows a notification instantly after the test finishes).  I think the problem must be in guard-minitest, I'm investigating that now...